How to mock mongoDb for unit tests, Jobrunr is using mongoDb as storage Provider
Please refere below code snipped
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.bson.UuidRepresentation;
import org.jobrunr.storage.StorageProvider;
import org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.documentdb.AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Value("${mongodb.host}")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Value("${mongodb.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${mongodb.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public StorageProvider getStorageProvider() {
        return getAmazonDocumentDB();
    }

    private AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider getAmazonDocumentDB() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(getAmazonDocumentDbConnectionString());
        MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connectionString);
        final MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY)
                .build();
        final MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
        return new AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider(mongoClient);
    }

    private String getAmazonDocumentDbConnectionString() {
        final String template = "mongodb://%s:%s@%s/?replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=%s&retryWrites=false";
        final String username = this.username;
        final String password = this.password;
        final String host = this.mongoHost;
        final String readPreference = "secondaryPreferred";
        return String.format(template, username, password, host, readPreference);
    }
}


I want to write unit tests for the above Configuration to pass sonar test in pipeline(95% coverage is required) But I am unable to mock mongoDb.
Below is the code written for unit test
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})
public class BeanConfigTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BeanConfig beanConfig;

    @Value("${mongodb.host}")
    private String mongoHost = "localhost:27017";

    @Value("${mongodb.username}")
    private String username = "user";

    @Value("${mongodb.password}")
    private String password = "pass";
    ;

    private static MockedStatic<MongoClientSettings> mongoClientSettings = Mockito.mockStatic(MongoClientSettings.class);

    private static MockedStatic<MongoClients> mongoClients = Mockito.mockStatic(MongoClients.class);

    private static MongoClient mockMongoClient = Mockito.mock(MongoClient.class);

    @InjectMocks
    private ActionHandler actionHandler;

    @Mock
    private StorageService storageService;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(){
        mongoClients.when(() -> MongoClients.create(any(MongoClientSettings.class))).thenReturn(mockMongoClient);
    }


    @Test
    public void testActionHandler() {
        StorageProvider storageProvider = beanConfig.getStorageProvider();
        assertNotNull(storageProvider);
    }

Getting below error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase.getCollection(String)" because "this.jobrunrDatabase" is null

    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBCreator.<init>(MongoDBCreator.java:49)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBCreator.<init>(MongoDBCreator.java:42)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.documentdb.AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider.runMigrations(AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider.java:59)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBStorageProvider.setUpStorageProvider(MongoDBStorageProvider.java:145)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBStorageProvider.<init>(MongoDBStorageProvider.java:126)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBStorageProvider.<init>(MongoDBStorageProvider.java:111)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.mongo.MongoDBStorageProvider.<init>(MongoDBStorageProvider.java:91)
    at org.jobrunr.storage.nosql.documentdb.AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider.<init>(AmazonDocumentDBStorageProvider.java:26)
    at com.cs.config.BeanConfig.getAmazonDocumentDB(BeanConfig.java:39)
    at com.cs.config.BeanConfig.getStorageProvider(BeanConfig.java:28)
    at com.cs.config.BeanConfigTest.testActionHandler(BeanConfigTest.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)


please guide me How to write unit tests for the COnfiguration Class mentioned above.
Trying to write unit tests, but unable to mock mongo and jobrunr dependencies.

@Value is a Spring annotation and does not have any effect outside of Spring. You are running your test with MockitoExtension, so Spring is not involved. Mockito will not assign values to your @Value-annotated fields.

I don't think that MockedStatic should be evaluated in the field initializer of a static field. It should be set in the test where you need it.

You shouldn't be writing unit tests for your configuration classes, you should be writing functional tests that use this configuration. Use an embedded mongodb or use testcontainers to bootstrap Mongo for testing.
